# Objective-C get steps data by HealthKit if source is from Apple Watch get apple watch data

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I get steps by health kit (health app) Show below code .  but if source is apple watch then i get steps only helth app which source iphone . i need to get apple watch steps which show in apple watch .
i want to fetch apple watch steps not iphone if i have apple watch in source .

```
enter code here

-(void)getHistoryoffUserSteps {
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
interval.day = 1;
NSDateComponents *anchorComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
anchorComponents.hour = 0;
NSDate *anchorDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:anchorComponents];
HKQuantityType *quantityType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];
// Create the query
HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:quantityType quantitySamplePredicate:nil options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum
                                                                                    anchorDate:anchorDate intervalComponents:interval];

query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Perform proper error handling here
        NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: %@ ***",error.localizedDescription);
    }
    apiStepHistryData=@"";
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                           value:-1
                                          toDate:[NSDate date]
                                         options:0];
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                             value:-31
                                            toDate:endDate
                                           options:0];


    [results enumerateStatisticsFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate withBlock:^(HKStatistics *result, BOOL *stop) {
        HKQuantity *quantity = result.sumQuantity;
        if (quantity) {
            NSDate *date = result.startDate;
            NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
            NSString*strDate=[format stringFromDate:date];
            double value = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit countUnit]];
            NSString*stepsappend=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%.0f",value];
            apiStepHistryData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,""%@""%@",apiStepHistryData,strDate,stepsappend];


        }

    }

     ];

};

[healthStore executeQuery:query];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(apiforUpdateSTepsData) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

});
```

}

Comment: Please share your code and describe the problem in detail for community to help!

Comment: hi i write code now . in this i get history of steps when source is iphone if i connected apple watch to my phone then i get same steps by iphone , i need to get apple watch steps if watch is connected to i i phone as a source type . @manu thanks